# Can I travel to Australia with my UN traveling document?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration

I have a refugee travel document (UN Passport) issued to me by Greece.

I would like to travel to Australia or Canada.  Do I need a visa for this travel?

Comment: What is your question?  Please elaborate on what you are trying to find out.

Comment: I have a refugee travel document issued to me from Greece but I have intention of traveling to Australia so do I need a visa or is it visa free for me ?